# Choose between ArrayAdapter and SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, simpleadapter

I was wondering, is there any guideline, on how we choose between `ArrayAdapter` and `SimpleAdapter`.

For every list item, they will be presented by several TextViews and Views, which is being layout nicely. I realize I can implement both without any problem, by either using `ArrayAdapter` or `SimpleAdapter`.

Is there any guideline, on how we choose among them? My guess is

1. `ArrayAdapter` enables us to add in new item dynamically, even after the list is being shown during that time. Note that, `ArrayAdapter` is having method `add`.
2. `SimpleAdapter` is used for case, once the list is being shown, there are no more new item can be added.

Is this the guideline we should follow?

Comment: I think you are right. The difference between the two is whether you are adding new elements dynamically (`ArrayAdapter`) or not (`SimpleAdapter`). At least, this is what I understand from the official documentation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Personally, I don't find `SimpleAdapter` terribly useful. Your model data is rarely naturally in "an `ArrayList` of `Maps`", and it is wasteful to be copying stuff around just to get it in an adapter.

I would either use `ArrayAdapter` (if my model data is an array of objects) or `BaseAdapter` (if my model data is some other in-memory data structure).

Answer (score -1):

Array Adapter could be used to fill out a list view from a dynamic array while the simple adapter is used to fill the list view from a Hash Map or Associative array because there is no constructor in the Array adapter that could take An array of keys and an array of int which is the layout ids we want to fill the data in.